# What is the expected behavior of tellg() when std::stringstream is constructed with ("some content", std::ios::in|std::ios::ate)?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, libstdc++

I have the following piece of code that surprised me (using libstdc++4.8)...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string s("some content");
    std::stringstream ss(s, std::ios::in|std::ios::ate);
    std::istream& file = ss;
    //ss.clear(); Makes no difference...
    std::cout << "tellg() pos: " << file.tellg() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

... which has the following output.

> tellg() pos: 0

This behaviour is different to when using std::ifstream(std::ios::ate).

- Is this behaviour correct/expected?
- Does one need to explictly seekg(0, std::ios::end) despite opening with ate?
- clearing the state doesn't make a difference.
- Please note that the string **has content**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fully in-line with what standard tells us. Here are relevant details:

The version of constructor you've used:

> Constructs a std::basic_stringbuf object by calling the default constructor of std::basic_streambuf, initializes the character sequence with an empty string, and sets the mode to which, than followed by initializing the associated
>   character sequence as if by calling str(new_str).

Default constructor of `basic_stringbuf` is not interesting here, and than `std::basic_stringbuf::str`:

> Deletes the entire underlying character sequence of this
>   std::basic_stringbuf and then configures a new underlying character
>   sequence containing a copy of the contents of s. ... For append
>   streams (mode & ios_base::ate == true), pptr() == pbase() + s.size(),
>   so that subsequent output will be appended to the last character
>   copied from s

And finally, `tellg()`, which calls `pubseekoff` on the buffer:

> If which includes ios_base::in and this buffer is open for reading
>   (that is, if ((which & ios_base::in) == ios_base::in), then
>   repositions the read pointer std::basic_streambuf::gptr: .. then newoff is the current position of the pointer (gptr()-eback() in this case)

To sum it up: since you didn't modify get position in any way (constructor only modifies put position), it returns 0.

Comment: This is an interesting decision. The effect is that for tests that rely on a factory returning iostream, the behavior of creating a fstream(mode) and a stringstream(mode) object in input only mode (ios::in) differs. I've used std::stringstream for simulating "in memory" files in tests, and code mostly rely on either istream, ostream or iostream. The difference in behavior made my tests fail unexpectedly.

Comment: Also, for me here is a slight lack of "Is-A" relationship. Granted, a filestream is not a stringstream, but I feel there would have been value in making the behaviour of ios::in | ios::ate more "heterogeneous"

Comment: Well, exactly. File stream is not string stream, and there is no 'is-a' relationship between them. So I do not see an immediate *defect* in standard. Yet, I would admit, I do not see why get pointer can't be updated for string buffer as well when `str()` is called. You might want to submit a change proposal for this.

Answer (score 2):

#### In short:

`tellg()` returns `gptr()-eback()` and providing the `ios_base::in` flag in the `stringstream` (and therefore the `basic_stringbuf`) constructor has the postcondition `gptr() == eback()`.

Thus, `0` is expected / enforced.

#### In long:

- `tellg()` returns `rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in)`
- `rdbuf()` returns `const_cast<basic_stringbuf*>(&sb)`.
- `pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in)` calls `seekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in)`
- `seekoff` returns `gptr()-eback()`
- `eback()` returns a pointer to the beginning of the get area
- `gptr()` returns the current get point

`stringstream` Initialization:

> `basic_stringstream (basic_string const &str, ios_base::openmode which);`
>
> Effects: Constructs an object of class basic_stringstream, initializing the base class with `basic_iostream(&sb)` and initializing sb with `basic_stringbuf(str, which)`.
>
> `basic_stringbuf(basic_string const &str, ios_base::openmode which)`
>
> Effects: Constructs an object of class basic_stringbuf, initializing the base class with `basic_streambuf()`, and initializing mode with which. Then calls `str(s)`.
>
> `void basic_stringbuf::str(const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& s);`
>
> Effects: Copies the content of s into the basic_stringbuf underlying character sequence and initializes the input and output sequences according to mode.
>
> Postconditions:
>
> - If `mode & ios_base::out` is `true`, `pbase()` points to the first underlying character and `epptr() >= pbase() + s.size()` holds;
> - if `mode & ios_base::ate` is `true`, `pptr() == pbase() + s.size()` holds, otherwise `pptr() == pbase()` is `true`.
> - If `mode & ios_base::in` is `true`, `eback()` points to the first underlying character, and both `gptr() == eback()` and `egptr() == eback() + s.size()` hold.

Where the last bit is relevant: providing `ios_base::in` has the postcondition `gptr() == eback()` and since `tellg()` returns `gptr()-eback()` the result is required to be zero.

Comment: "If mode & ios_base::in is true, eback() points to the first underlying character" ... does not reflect intuitive behavior, IM(h)O.

Comment: @WernerErasmus: A file has one "position pointer" where `stringstream` has two. One for reading and one for writing. I don't see an immediate benefit of having both of the at the end when providing `ate` Imo it is actually a good thing that you can use `ate` to append to the string while still being able to read from the stringstream from the beginning. The only thing that is a bit counterintuitive to me is the fact that a string initialized `strinstream{str}` (without `ate`) does not append to `str` when using `operator<<` but otoh there is no `atb` to reverse that behaviour if default.